# Laravel boot problem - General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I use Laravel with MySQL on XAMMP.

I am currently trying to make a simple relationship between my `users` table and my `profiles` table. When a new user is created i want to create a profile for that specific user at the same time. Referencing my uuid "id" from the users table to the "user_id" in the profiles table. So i can reference the two in my application.

For that i added a boot function to my "User" model. And im trying

Now when i create a new user i get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default
>   value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Jesper Deleuran Larsen,
>   jesperdeleuranlarsen@gmail.com,
>   $2y$10$mA4jZINdWhJXfbBihilI0.Lqmn3L5iTs9m7yI/tAuI5FWBVkIdYxu,
>   2019-06-02 19:56:11, 2019-06-02 19:56:11))

If i erase the boot function in the User model it works fine and generates a new user but the profiles table is of course empty. So i guess the error is somewhere in the model but i just cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Since im a beginner please tell me if the whole thing is setup the wrong way.

Much appreciated!

My User model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Mail\NewUserWelcomeMail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Uuids; //UUID
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->create();
        });
    }


    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

My migration for the users table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->primary('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

My migration for the profiles table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->uuid('user_id');
            $table->string('company')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            //Linking profiles table to users table
            $table->index('user_id');
        });




    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

My profile model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{

    use Uuids; //UUID

    //Disable fillable
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'user_id', 'company', 'phone',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

My trait for creating userids = uuids.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: public $incrementing = false; and id does not have default value

Comment: What package are you using for the UUID? Looks like the Uuids trait uses the boot method to define the uuid, but you are rewriting it when you define your own boot method. If the trait is written by yourself, please post it. It's bad written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess without seeing your `Uuids` trait:

You (or the package maintener) uses the `boot()` method. It works, but prevents you from using it when defining you own boot method on the model.

To solve this kind of problem, Laravel implements a trait boot method ([see this](https://laravel-news.com/booting-eloquent-model-traits)).

To use it just rename the `boot()` method of your trait to `bootUuids()` and it should work!

Comment: Hello Elias
Thank you so much for your answer. I got it to work by following the guide you linked! I changed it to this and now it runs perfectly 

  public static function bootUuids()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });

        
    }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Changed my "Uuids.php"

From:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });


    }

}
```

To:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    public static function bootUuids()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate()->string;
        });


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the first thing to check here is if you're ID column is auto incrementing. Taking a quick peek at the documentation, neither `->uuid()` nor `->primary()` set the column to be auto incremented oddly enough.

If you don't actually want an auto-incrementing string (since you're using uuid's this is totally fine) we'd need to see where you're creating the user, as you'll need to pass the ID to the user when creating it.

Let me know if you still need a hand after checking.

Comment: He's using a package to make the uuid. Also the problems isn't with the migration since when ihe remove the boot method from model it works.

Comment: Hey Dylan. Thank you for your answer. The package im using does the auto-incrementing for me as mentioned. The problem was the boot functions somehow interfering with each other. I guess it tried to create my profiles table with the user_id link before the actual users table.